# Add Admin User via SQL

Tags: admin, database, users, sql

I gave my client the admin account to his wordpress install and I forgot to add an administrator user for myself. Now, I can no longer access the admin panel because they have changed their password. I have direct access to the database and was wondering if I could inject a new admin user via SQL?

Comment: Ask the client to add an admin account for you? Why do you need to inject data if you are permitted to access this site's database, or you own the server.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to bother my client. Also, by "inject" I meant writing SQL directly to the DB.

Comment: Mentioned where? ... I think the answer you have from patnz covers it(everything you need)... just strikes me as a little strange is all..

Comment: My bad, thought I mentioned it but must have all been in my head... sorry about that.

Comment: I do that to... no worries.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to do from phpMyadmin. I've used [this tutorial](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database) before successfully.