# SQL Query to Update Admin Email

Tags: database, admin, email-verification

After pushing a staging site to production I have `admin@example.test` set as the admin email which I need to change. Obviously I can't access that email to verify the change because it doesn't exist so I wrote this query:

```sql
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'admin@example.com' WHERE option_name = 'admin_email'
```

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34986/add-admin-user-via-sql) related answer but I do not use phpMyAdmin.

Is this an OK method to override this? Or is there a more proper method?

Comment: Ideally you'd do this via [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/), or you could use [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/)'s [`option update` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/) - something like `wp option update admin_email admin@example.com` would do it.

Comment: @PatJ so just `update_option( 'admin_email', 'admin@example.com' );` in `functions.php` then remove it? I don't use WP-CLI on prod.

Comment: That should do it, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your SQL query will probably do the trick, you don't need to interface directly with the database to accomplish this.

The preferred methods would by using Wordpress' `update_option()` function or by running the WP-CLI command:`wp option update`.

### Via `update_option()`

To override the admin email change confirmation process, add the following to your `functions.php` file and hit "save changes".

`update_option( 'admin_email', 'correct.admin@example.com' );`

Then once you've verified that the change worked, you can go back to your `functions.php` and remove the snippet.

---

### Via WP-CLI

If you have WP-CLI installed, you can run the following command from your shell/terminal (much faster):

`wp option update admin_email correct.admin@example.com`

If WP-CLI is owned by root, you'll obviously need to run it with `sudo`. Success will give you the following output:

`Success: Updated 'admin_email' option.`